# Yield Rails 2 vs Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2, yield

I was in process of migrating a rails 2 app to rails 3. While doing this i came accross a wiered behaviour with yield.
I have a code snippet where i get the return value of yield.

```
x= true if yield 'xyz'
```

So if content_for exists for 'xyz' the value of x will be set true else nothing happens. It works fine in rails 2. But in rails 3, always true is set to x because **rails returns an empty string even if 'xyz' is not available**.

In Rails 2:

```
yield 'xyz' # nil if xyz is not available
yield 'xyz' # "hi" if xyz is available. "hi" is the rendered content
```

In Rails 3:

```
yield 'xyz' # "" if xyz is not available
yield 'xyz' # "hi" if xyz is available. "hi" is the rendered content
```

Why is this change? render_template has been changed completly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not answer your questions but I'd recommend to use this approach:

```
if content_for?(:xyz)
  yield(:xyz)
  x = true
end
```

Comment: Ya thats what i finally ended with. x=true if content_for?('xyz')